# The properties of real numbers field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, real-numbers

1. I know, that the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}$ is create on the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. But how we can multiply real numbers on the $0$ after this?

This point was unswered, I think. But for now, I cannot understand, why we can say that $\mathbb{R}$ -- field. I think that field -- is a $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Becouse in $\mathbb{R}$ exist non-unit element.

2. Is the equation $ax = b$ unsolvable if $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b = 0$ or this equation has infinite number of roots (the all real numbers)? I think the first (becouse $0$ doesn't unit element in multiplication group), but not sure.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The 1. I realy cannot understand. Becouse, if we define the operation on set without some elements, how can we use this operation on the elements that exist outside of this set...

Comment: We do not define multiplication on the non zero reals. We define it for all reals. Restricted to the non zero reals we then prove it is a group. For Q2 you should first decide whether you are discussing the equation in the semi group (all reals) or the group (non zero reals).

Comment: I have no idea what your asking for 1. it sounds like your asking "if we ignore $0$ to get the multiplicative group how can we un-ignore $0$ to get the full multiplication" and it's a bit like saying "once I put on pants, how can I be pant-less again since I am now wearing pants?"

Comment: @Shahab So, we define the all axioms of field on the all elements of $\mathbb{R}$, but the existence of inverse elements we define only for nonzero elements? And after that we have field structure on the set $\mathbb{R}$ or in the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$? 


Ammm, I think that this equation in the field, not only in group or in semigroup..

Comment: @TrevorGunn I can not understand what kind of carrier structure set in real numbers field. I know the carrier structure set of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ groups: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, but not for field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For each real number $a\ne 0$, $a0 = 0 = 0a$, since $a0 = a(a+(-a)) = a^2 - a^2=0$. Similar for $0a$. So $0$ is absorbing. It holds for every ring.